# How to go back to the last activity when the app is killed and reopened

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

I want my Android app to go back to the last activity if the user closes and reopens the app again. I search for some info, but most of them just save the data. I am wondering how to save the activity. For example, my app has two activities, the app was killed when it was in activity 2. When I relaunch the app, it should go to activity 2 instead of activity 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use 1 `Activity` and 2 `Fragment`; then use `Bundle savedInstanceState`.

Comment: Right now I used SharePerfences to solve this problem. Is there any potential problem with that? What is the difference between Bundle savedInstanceState and SharePerfences?

Comment: The one had been particularly designed for that purpose, while the other not (it's abuse)... there's still a slight difference in between "somehow working" and "working as it's meant to be".